# Smart Contracts developed for Ethereum can also be used in Binance Smart Chain?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, binance

I'm newcomer to blockchain and i'm starting to develop a new token, and i've seen many places telling the similarities between the two blockchains. And i read that BSC have a EVM(Ethereum Virtual Machine) compatibility My question is if that means If I follow a tutorial to learn do deploy a smart contract on the Ethereum blockchain, written in Solidity. Will the same contract work in the Binance Smart Chain too? If not, what are the major diferrences when writting contracts for one and the other? Thank you

Comment: Yes Binance forked the EVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly true. It's also true for any other EVM-compatible blockchain.